# How to remove all newlines from selected region in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, replace, newline

How to remove all newlines from selected region in Emacs?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

1. `M-x replace-string`
2. `C-q C-j`
3. `RET`
4. `RET`

The trick is to quote the `C-j` with `C-q`, but otherwise replacing newlines is like replacing anything else.

Comment: If you are working with text, it's probably more practical to replace with a space instead.

Comment: What about `unfill-region`, would that do it?

Comment: is unfill-region provided in emacs, or do you have to add it in yourself?

Answer (score 15):

With my key bindings, which I think are standard, on windows:

Select region

shift-alt-%

ctrl-Q ctrl-J

return

return

!

Or to put it another way, query replace region, ctrl-q to get extended characters, ctrl-j to put in a newline, replace with nothing, all of them.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to create a function to do this (and bind it to <kbd>F8</kbd>) you could try:

```lisp
(defun remove-newlines-in-region ()
  "Removes all newlines in the region."
  (interactive)
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (point) (mark))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\n" nil t) (replace-match "" nil t))))

(global-set-key [f8] 'remove-newlines-in-region)
```

That's based on an example I that I [found here](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_replace_string_region.html).

Answer (score -2):

You might also consider the old standby `delete-blank-lines`, typically bound to <kbd>C-x C-o</kbd>.

Comment: That won't work, except in the unlikely event that all the newlines are blank lines.